# Get the block timestamp using subxt

Tags: rust, subxt

I am using subxt to get the block details, including the block number, hash, parent hash, timestamp, events and the extrinsics.

I am able to find most details, except the timestamp. Is there a way to get the block inclusion time?

Following is how I get the block details.

[image]

Is it possible to get the block timestamp using the subxt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamp is an item stored in storage.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/91deee7a1dba52e5e73d1a97d9fd5b8ad1e916a4/substrate/frame/timestamp/src/lib.rs#L156-L159C13

Simply retrieve it from storage.

Follow this [example](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/subxt/examples/storage_fetch.rs) and replace `system().account()` with `timestamp().now()`.

Comment: thank you, this solved my problem.